# Show that $A \cup B$ and $C$ are independent as well

Tags: probability-theory

Show that if 3 events ($A$, $B$ and $C$) are independent, that the events $A \cup B$ and $C$ are independent as well.

It seems pretty logically straightforward but how do you show this statistically.

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A) \times P(B)$. So if $(P(A \cup B) \cap P(C)) = P(A \cup B) \times P(C)$ then they are independent.

Comment: Start at the *definition* of being independent.

Comment: Start with the definition of independence: how can you use that $A, B, C$ are independent events? Unpack definitions, and the meaning of $A\cup B$ $(x \in A \lor x \in B)$. All your probability problems the last couple of days have stated precisely what this post states. (1) "Problem statement" followed by (2) "It seems logical...or ...I can see this intuitively...". (3) and they *all* have ended in "... **but** how do you show this statistically."  It's getting old. It's feeling like you've been posting all your assigned problems for *us* to do. It's time you start working.

Comment: Well $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B)$. $P(A \cap C) = P(A) \times P(C)$. $P(B \cap C) = P(B) \times P(C)$. If they are independent, it means that the occurrence of one event does not affect the occurrence of another. Please give me some advice on how to relate independent events to unions as opposed to intersections

Comment: $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A) \times P(B)$. So if $(P(A \cup B) \cap P(C)) = P(A \cup B) \times P(C)$ then they are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two events $X$ and $Y$ are **independent** if 
$$
\Bbb P(X\cap Y)=\Bbb P(X)\cdot\Bbb P(Y)
$$
Three events $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are **mutually** independent if 
$$
\Bbb P(X\cap Y\cap Z)=\Bbb P(X)\cdot\Bbb P(Y)\cdot\Bbb P(Z)
$$
A standard exercise shows that mutually independent events $\{X,Y,Z\}$ are always **pairwise independent**, meaning that
\begin{align*}
\Bbb P(X\cap Y) &= \Bbb P(X)\cdot\Bbb P(Y) & \Bbb P(X\cap Z) &= \Bbb P(X)\cdot\Bbb P(Z) & \Bbb P(Y\cap Z) &= \Bbb P(Y)\cdot\Bbb P(Z)
\end{align*}
Therefore you are trying to show that
$$
\Bbb P\big((A\cup B)\cap C\big)=\Bbb P(A\cup B)\cdot\Bbb P(C)
$$
To do so, note that 
\begin{align*}
\Bbb P\big((A\cup B)\cap C\big)
&= \Bbb P\big((A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)\big) \\
&= \Bbb P(A\cap C)+\Bbb P(B\cap C)-\Bbb P\big((A\cap C)\cap (B\cap C)\big) \\
\end{align*}
If I am interpreting your problem correctly, you are assuming that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are mutually independent. 
Can you use this assumption to further manipulate this equation?

Comment: Are you asking me because you don't know how or just because you want me to do it because I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: I certainly know how. I'm trying to nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: $P((A \cap C) \cap (B \cap C)) = P(A \cap B \cap C)$ so the entire thing $= P(A)P(C) + P(B)P(C) - P(A)P(B)P(C) = P(C) \times ( P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B) ) = P(C) \times ( P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) ) =P(C)P(A \cup B)$

Comment: Yes. Now you're done.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad you helped me get there by myself :)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
p((A \cup B) \cap C) &=& p((A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)) \\
&=& p(A \cap C) + p(B \cap C) - p((A \cap C) \cap (B \cap C)) \\
&=& pA pC + pB pC - pA pB pC \\
&=& (pA + pB - pA pB) pC \\
&=& p(A \cup B) pC
\end{eqnarray}